# Нужен скрипт для плавного удаления градиента

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужен скрипт который также будет плавно убирать градиент как и все остальные элементы, вот ссылка на  [codepen](https://codepen.io/DmitriyKurtsev/pen/abzqeLx)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1440px;
  padding-top: 82px;
  background-image: url(header-bgc.jpg);
}

.team__card {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 447px;
  width: 360px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  -ms-border-radius: 1px;
  -o-border-radius: 1px;
}

.team__card:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(109, 105, 105, 0.85) 50%), url(fff.jpg);
}

.team__card:hover .team__skills_naming-progress {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-10px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-10px);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.7s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: 0.7s;
  -ms-transition: 0.7s;
  -o-transition: 0.7s;
}

.team__card:hover .team__progress01 {
  width: 123px;
  transition: 1.2s;
  -webkit-transition: 1.2s;
  -moz-transition: 1.2s;
  -ms-transition: 1.2s;
  -o-transition: 1.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.team__card:hover .team__progress02 {
  width: 109px;
  transition: 1.2s;
  -webkit-transition: 1.2s;
  -moz-transition: 1.2s;
  -ms-transition: 1.2s;
  -o-transition: 1.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.team__card:hover .team__progress03 {
  width: 116px;
  transition: 1.2s;
  -webkit-transition: 1.2s;
  -moz-transition: 1.2s;
  -ms-transition: 1.2s;
  -o-transition: 1.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.team__card:hover .team__skills_data {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-10px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-10px);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
}

.team__card:hover .team__card_block_name-desc {
  transform: translateY(-15px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-15px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-15px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-15px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.4s;
  cursor: default;
  z-index: -1;
}

.team__skills_naming-progress {
  width: 149px;
  height: 84px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.4s;
}

.team__skills_naming {
  margin-top: 13px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #423e3d;
}

.team__scale {
  width: 150px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  -ms-border-radius: 1px;
  -o-border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: #817f7e;
}

.team__progress01 {
  width: 0;
  height: 4px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  -ms-border-radius: 1px;
  -o-border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: #ff6e47;
  transition: 0.7s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: 0.7s;
  -ms-transition: 0.7s;
  -o-transition: 0.7s;
}

.team__progress02 {
  width: 0;
  height: 4px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  -ms-border-radius: 1px;
  -o-border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: #ff6e47;
  transition: 0.7s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: 0.7s;
  -ms-transition: 0.7s;
  -o-transition: 0.7s;
}

.team__progress03 {
  width: 0;
  height: 4px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  -ms-border-radius: 1px;
  -o-border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: #ff6e47;
  transition: 0.7s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: 0.7s;
  -ms-transition: 0.7s;
  -o-transition: 0.7s;
}

.team__skills_data {
  position: absolute;
  width: 170px;
  height: 85px;
  bottom: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.2s;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
}

.team__skills_name {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #565352;
}

.team__skills_desc {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #ff8b6f;
}

.team__skills_soc-nets {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 72px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.team__card_block_name-desc {
  position: absolute;
  width: 262px;
  padding-top: 21px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -131px;
  padding-bottom: 19px;
  margin-bottom: -23px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -ms-border-radius: 2px;
  -o-border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #c0c0c0;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.4s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.team__name {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #737373;
}

.team__desc {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #8b8b8b;
}
```

```html
<div class="team__card">
  <div class="team__skills_naming-progress">
    <div class="team__skills_naming">UI/UX Design</div>
    <div class="team__scale">
      <div class="team__progress01"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="team__skills_naming">English</div>
    <div class="team__scale">
      <div class="team__progress02"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="team__skills_naming">Communication</div>
    <div class="team__scale">
      <div class="team__progress03"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="team__skills_data">
    <div class="team__skills_name">Bedi Manos</div>
    <div class="team__skills_desc">UI/UX Parena</div>
    <div class="team__skills_soc-nets">
      <a href="#"><img src="team__skills_soc-nets01.png" /> </a>
      <a href="#"><img src="team__skills_soc-nets02.png" /> </a>
      <a href="#"><img src="team__skills_soc-nets01.png" /> </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="team__card_block_name-desc">
    <div class="team__name">Bedi Manos</div>
    <div class="team__desc">UI/UX Parena</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: у вас есть ещё возможность поблагодарить автора ответа, кроме `спасибо` плюсом и отметить решение галочкой

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самый простой вариант который я вижу, использовать псевдо-элемент с градиентом и в момент наведение на родителя, ставить прозрачность псевдо-элементу.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1440px;
  padding-top: 82px;
  background-image: url(header-bgc.jpg);
}

.team__card {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 447px;
  width: 360px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  -ms-border-radius: 1px;
  -o-border-radius: 1px;
}

/* Изменения тут */
.team__card::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(109, 105, 105, 0.85) 50%), url(fff.jpg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.7s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: 0.7s;
  -ms-transition: 0.7s;
  -o-transition: 0.7s;
}

.team__card:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.team__card * {
  z-index: 2;
}
/*---------------*/

.team__card:hover .team__skills_naming-progress {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-10px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-10px);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.7s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: 0.7s;
  -ms-transition: 0.7s;
  -o-transition: 0.7s;
}

.team__card:hover .team__progress01 {
  width: 123px;
  transition: 1.2s;
  -webkit-transition: 1.2s;
  -moz-transition: 1.2s;
  -ms-transition: 1.2s;
  -o-transition: 1.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.team__card:hover .team__progress02 {
  width: 109px;
  transition: 1.2s;
  -webkit-transition: 1.2s;
  -moz-transition: 1.2s;
  -ms-transition: 1.2s;
  -o-transition: 1.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.team__card:hover .team__progress03 {
  width: 116px;
  transition: 1.2s;
  -webkit-transition: 1.2s;
  -moz-transition: 1.2s;
  -ms-transition: 1.2s;
  -o-transition: 1.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.team__card:hover .team__skills_data {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-10px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-10px);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  z-index: 2;
}

.team__card:hover .team__card_block_name-desc {
  transform: translateY(-15px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-15px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-15px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-15px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.4s;
  cursor: default;
}

.team__skills_naming-progress {
  width: 149px;
  height: 84px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.4s;
}

.team__skills_naming {
  margin-top: 13px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #423e3d;
}

.team__scale {
  width: 150px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  -ms-border-radius: 1px;
  -o-border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: #817f7e;
}

.team__progress01 {
  width: 0;
  height: 4px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  -ms-border-radius: 1px;
  -o-border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: #ff6e47;
  transition: 0.7s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: 0.7s;
  -ms-transition: 0.7s;
  -o-transition: 0.7s;
}

.team__progress02 {
  width: 0;
  height: 4px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  -ms-border-radius: 1px;
  -o-border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: #ff6e47;
  transition: 0.7s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: 0.7s;
  -ms-transition: 0.7s;
  -o-transition: 0.7s;
}

.team__progress03 {
  width: 0;
  height: 4px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  -ms-border-radius: 1px;
  -o-border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: #ff6e47;
  transition: 0.7s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: 0.7s;
  -ms-transition: 0.7s;
  -o-transition: 0.7s;
}

.team__skills_data {
  position: absolute;
  width: 170px;
  height: 85px;
  bottom: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.2s;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
}

.team__skills_name {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #565352;
}

.team__skills_desc {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #ff8b6f;
}

.team__skills_soc-nets {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 72px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.team__card_block_name-desc {
  position: absolute;
  width: 262px;
  padding-top: 21px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -131px;
  padding-bottom: 19px;
  margin-bottom: -23px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -ms-border-radius: 2px;
  -o-border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #c0c0c0;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.4s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.team__name {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #737373;
}

.team__desc {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #8b8b8b;
}
```

```html
<div class="team__card">
  <div class="team__skills_naming-progress">
    <div class="team__skills_naming">UI/UX Design</div>
    <div class="team__scale">
      <div class="team__progress01"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="team__skills_naming">English</div>
    <div class="team__scale">
      <div class="team__progress02"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="team__skills_naming">Communication</div>
    <div class="team__scale">
      <div class="team__progress03"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="team__skills_data">
    <div class="team__skills_name">Bedi Manos</div>
    <div class="team__skills_desc">UI/UX Parena</div>
    <div class="team__skills_soc-nets">
      <a href="#"><img src="team__skills_soc-nets01.png" </a>
        <a href="#"><img src="team__skills_soc-nets02.png" </a>
          <a href="#"><img src="team__skills_soc-nets01.png" </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="team__card_block_name-desc">
    <div class="team__name">Bedi Manos</div>
    <div class="team__desc">UI/UX Parena</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло